# RegEx in Python not matching

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as logs:
    for line in logs.readlines():
        reg = re.compile('publishing service \/rest\/service\/\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\state\s\w+\b.*');
        print(reg.search(line.strip()));
```

I am using above regex code for pattern matching. My string is as below

```
2019-01-17 19:41:40.445 UTC,INFO ,myapp:761,publishing service /rest/service /4ce2c885-3690-48ba-a1cb-bb1762859a39 state
```

But my code is not able to match this string. Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: Note that `\b` in your pattern is a backspace char. Add `r` prefix before the  regex string literal. Also, there is a space after `/rest/service` in the string, and no space is in your pattern. And you should have used `\sstate`, ``\state`` matches  a whitespace and `tate`.

Comment: What is the actual requirement? Note that `\s\w+` at the end assume there is text after `state`, but there is none. Try `r'publishing service /rest/service\s*/\w+(?:-\w+){4}\sstate\b'`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/KnyHPB/2).

Comment: using `r` worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed an `s` and use `r` ([raw string](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)):

```
reg = re.compile(r'publishing service/rest/service\s*/\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+\sstate\b');
#         here __^                                                  here __^
```

Comment: you should also mention the usage of `r`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub That does not fix the issue anyway. This regex [still does not help](https://regex101.com/r/qpf2sL/1).

Answer (score -1):

update your regex:

```
reg = re.compile('publishing service /rest/service /\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-* state')
```